# I can't get images to change in image slider

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I can't get the images to change in the waving slider according to images in array even tough the backgroundImage url changes in the divelement as observed with dev tools. It also keeps creating divelement endlessly

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')
const subcontainer = document.getElementById('sub-container')
image = []
ang = []
compteur = 0
counter = 0
var counter
var compteur
var nb


window.onload = function() {
  imindex = 0
  nb = 20
  image = ["image/beach.jpg", "image/forest.jpg", "image/sunrise.jpg"]
  create()
}

function create() {
  for (j = 1; j <= nb; j++) {
    ang[j] = -j * 10
    divelement = document.createElement('div')
    divelement.className = ("divclass")
    divelement.style.height = (Math.round(subcontainer.clientHeight)) + 'px'
    divelement.style.width = (Math.round((subcontainer.clientWidth) / nb)) + 'px'
    divelement.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + image[imindex] + '")'
    divelement.style.backgroundPosition = (j * 100 / nb) + "%"
    divelement.style.visibility = "hidden"
    divelementID = "divelement" + j
    divelement.setAttribute('id', divelementID)
    subcontainer.appendChild(divelement)
    counter = j
  }
  animate();
}

function animate() {
  t = setTimeout("animate()", 10)
  for (i = 1; i <= nb; i++) {
    compteur = 20
    divelementID = "divelement" + i
    targetedDivElementID = document.getElementById(divelementID)
    targetedDivElementID.style.transform = "perspective(1000px) rotateY(" + ang[i] + "deg)"
    if (ang[i] > -90) {
      targetedDivElementID.style.visibility = "visible"
    }
    if (ang[i] < 0) {
      ang[i] += 1
    } else ang[i] = 0
    if (ang[compteur] == 0) {
      imindex += 1
      clearTimeout(t)
      create()
      if (imindex > image.length - 1) {
        imindex = 0
        clearTimeout(t)
        create()
      }
    }
  }
}

function removeimage() {
  for (j = 1; j <= nb; j++) {
    toremovediv = document.getElementsByClassName('divclass');
    subcontainer.removeChild(toremovediv[j])
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="sub-container" id="sub-container"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to remove created 'divelement' by calling the removeimage() function inside the if condition if(ang[compteur]==0){} but then I get error message 'my3Dslider.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
at removeimage' and as seen with the dev tool only the first 'divelement' with id=divelement1 remains and can't be removed. May somebody explains and help. Thanks a lot.